# How to iterate through a list while ignoring zero values

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a list while ignoring the zero values. The list consists of concentration values, for these values a calculation should be performed. At some points the concentration is zero and therefore the calculation will return an error. I do not know how to solve this. Ideally I would like to ignore the zeros in the list. Another option would be to let the calculation return zero when encountering an error. I tried to solve it with a try except. Then it returned a 'RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log' which I tried to ignore with the np.errstate line. Running this returns only one value for the first item in the list it seems. I want a value for every item in the list. I am very new to python and basically have no clue how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def calculate_deltaGr():
    deltaG0T = calculate_deltaG0()[0]
    deltaGr_list = []
    for Con1 in Con1_list:
        with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
            try:
                deltaGr = deltaG0T + R * T1 * np.log((Con1 ** n_con1) / ((Con2 ** n_con2) * (Con3 ** n_con3) * (Con4 ** n_con4)))
                deltaGr_list.append(deltaGr)
            except TypeError:
                return 0
            return deltaGr_list
```

Only con1 should be variable. Con2, Con3 and Con4 are fixed values

Comment: can you add some dummy values for all those other lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do anything when you get 0 use `continue`

```
for Con1 in Con1_list:
    if Con1 == 0: continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple if statement will work.  Using try/except isn't the best. You know that an input can be zero, so why not just check for it?  If you want a value as placeholder in the list, you can return a large out of range value, or return 0 as you are doing now.